# Trying to schedule x amount of notifications at the same time for x days

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

This is the function used to configure the notification. The index is used to increment the date and also to change the identifier for the notification.

```
func configNotification(someData: SomeDataType, index: Int) {
    guard let notificationTime = getNotificationTimeUserDefaults(),
        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: index, to: notificationTime) else { return }
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title       = someData.title
    content.subtitle    = someData.subtitle
    content.body        = someData.content
    content.badge       = index as NSNumber
    content.sound       = UNNotificationSound.default
    let tiggerDate      = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute], from: date)
    let trigger         = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: tiggerDate, repeats: false)
    let identifier      = "UYLLocalNotification\(index)"
    let request         = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (_) in })
}
```

Then to schedule x amount of notifications I call that function like so

```
func scheduleNotifications(numberOfNotifications: Int) {
    for i in numberOfNotifications {
        configNotification(someData: getSomeData(), index: i)
    }
}
```

I expect to receive only one notification at the next scheduled time which is set by the user.
However when I do this I receive more than one notification at the scheduled time.

The function used to retrieve the current user notification time is

```
func getNotificationTimeUserDefaults() -> Date? {
    var date: Date?
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: udNotificatonTime) != nil,
        let notificationTime = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: udNotificatonTime) {
        date = notificationTime as? Date
    }
    return date
}
```

The date picker where the user selects the notification time is

```
lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let p = UIDatePicker()
    p.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    p.setValue(Theme.current.textColor, forKeyPath: "textColor")
    p.backgroundColor   = .clear
    p.datePickerMode    = .time
    if let date = getNotificationTimeUserDefaults() {
        p.date = date
    }
    p.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    return p
}()
```

And then finally to set the user default notification time

```
@objc func dateChanged(p: UIDatePicker) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(p.date, forKey: Constants.Strings.udNotificatonTime)
    displayNotificationTime()
    scheduleNotifications(numberOfNotifications: x)
}
```

Again I'm simply trying to schedule x amount of notifications at the same time for x days. any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to verify your notifications using `getPendingNotificationRequests` method on `UNUserNotificationCenter` like this.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { [weak self] (requests) in
   print(requests)
}
```

Here you can debug all the notification against `identifier`, `calendar trigger` and `WeekDay`.

### Note:

Notification (creation/update) is dependent on `Identifier` you set. If you set the same identifier for new notification, notification with original identifier will be updated. So make sure you are doing as you intended.

So with this method you can verify why you are getting multiple notifications.

I hope this may help.